# Display ProgressBar while saving an image from Activity

Tags: java, android

In my app I am letting user save a drawing. While the drawing is saved, I want to display a progress bar on top of the drawing to let the user know it is saving.

My XML layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bd"
        android:id="@+id/llFreeDraw" >
    </LinearLayout>
    <ProgressBar 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large"
        android:id="@+id/pbSave"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Portion of my Java code is:

```
View.OnClickListener saveHandle = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        savePB = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbSave);
        savePB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        View content = layout;
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PB");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.mkdir();
        }
        file = new File(folder + "/pb_image_" + Math.random()  + ".png");
        FileOutputStream ostream;
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
            ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            ostream.flush();
            ostream.close();
            displayToast("Image was saved.");
            savePB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btnShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            displayToast("Unable to save image. Try again later.");
        }
    }
};
```

I want to display the progress bar on top of the framelayou, with a 25% transparent background. The image is saving but I do not see the progress bar. Any idea how to modify so it works the way I am wanting it to?

Comment: Do you see the progressbar, when setting it to visible in onCreate()?

Comment: I see the progress bar on the saved image :/ weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) can handle this.

```
public class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
         // Save your image here.
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPreExecute(){
         // Show your progress bar here.
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute() {
         // Hide the progress bar here.      
     }
 }
```

Call it like:

```
new SaveImageTask().execute(null, null, null);
```

Comment: The layout  also has to be changed I am guessing...?

Comment: So, change it to onPostExecute(Void v).

Comment: Thanks. Have to wait... SO says I must wait 30 mins :/